# Javascript file won't load using laragon (ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found))

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, laragon

I cannot use/access the `carousel.js` file - GET http://name.test/js/carousel.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

**front-page.php**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="carousel_item carousel_item--visible">first post</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="carousel_item">second post</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="carousel_item">third post</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel_actions">
        <button id="carousel_button--prev" aria-label="previous slide">
            <
        </button>
        <button id="carousel_button--next" aria-label="next slide">
            >
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/carousel.js"></script>""
```

**JS code:**

```
let slidePosition = 0;
const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel_item');
const totalSlides = slides.length;

document.getElementById('carousel_button--next').addEventListener("click", function() {
    moveToNextSlide();
});

document.getElementById('carousel_button--prev').addEventListener("click", function() {
    moveToPrevSlide();
});

function moveToNextSlide() {
    console.log('next works');
}

function moveToPrevSlide() {
    console.log('prev works');
}
```

**functions.php**

```
function load_js(){

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'jquery', false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
    wp_register_script('carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/carousel.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('carousel');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

**file structure**

```
.
├── js
│   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   └── carousel.js
├── index.php
├── front-page.php
└── functions.php
```

*(there are other files there, only included the important ones for an easier overview)*

I'm pretty sure I typed the correct path to the carousel.js file, can anyone enlighten me what's the problem here?

Comment: Seems that's wordpress. one question, I think you loaded the js in fuctions.php. but why you should load carouse.js in html?

Comment: good questions, I've now removed it and got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- In your `front-page.php` file, remove the `script tag`. (i.e `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/carousel.js"></script>`). Your `wp_enqueue_script` function would take care of loading it onto the page!

2- You don't need those `wp_register_script` functions either! In your `functions.php` file remove them!

3- In the `functions.php` file replace the following snippet with your own:

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');

function load_js()
{
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_theme_file_uri('/js/bootstrap.min.js'), 'jquery', 1.0, true);
  wp_enqueue_script('carousel', get_theme_file_uri('/js/carousel.js'), NULL, 1.0, true);
}
```

These should do the trick for you!

When you load the page, right-click on it and view the source. You should be able to find both `bootstrap` and `carousel` loaded onto the source!

Let me know if you could get it to work!

Comment: Oh my god it works!! Thank you so much Ruvee. May I ask what does the NULL there represent? It seems that solved the issue.

Comment: Null means it does not need any dependency! [Read more about it on the documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Answer (score 0):

So if you use Laravel, you need to use webpack.mix.js to integrate your JS

Comment: You don't need to if the file is linked correctly.

Comment: but is it linked correctly? btw its laragon, not laravel. should I try on xampp instead?